# TF1 from TF2 How to get the probability of the model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, model, probability

Hi I have the following model generated and I have successfully convert the TF 1 example o TF 2 using the Tf migration script.

Here is the model:

```
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph
X       = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs],name="input")
y       = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs],name="output")

layers  = [tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units     = n_neurons,
                                  activation    = tf.nn.leaky_relu, 
                                  use_peepholes = True,
                                  name          = "layer"+str(layer))  for layer in range(n_layers)
          ]
multi_layer_cell    = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs     = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs             = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs             = tf.identity(outputs[:, n_steps-1, :], name="prediction")

loss                = tf.math.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y))) # loss function = mean squared error                  

optimizer           = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate) 
training_op         = optimizer.minimize(loss, name = "training_op")
```

I want to know is it possible to get the probability of the Model? If it is possible then how I can add it in the above example? Secondly, I have seen `model.predict_proba`, but it is with the `keras` and I am not using `keras`.

Comment: What exactly is "the probability of the model"? Note that you are doing regression so no probabilities are involved here.

Answer (score 1):

The softmax activation function on the output layer can be used in computing probability of model prediction in TF2, if you are not using Keras, you should apply the softlmax function on the output layer.

```
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)logits = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])

# here we appy the softmax to get probabilities
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="probabilities")
```

Then you shoud evaluate the `probabilities` tensor using you X data inside an TF session.

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    model_probabilities = sess.run(probabilities, feed_dict={X: X})
```

Comment: Okay I will try this out. But is there any other way too?

Comment: Softmax is used for classification, here the OP is doing regression.